# React: Dynamically generated <select> elements - setting 'selected' state in a mapped element

Tags: forms, reactjs, lodash, setstate

I'm trying to handle the selection of dynamically generated `<option>`'s in a `<select>` element. I understand that the `onChange` trigger is what i need to setState with but i can't seem to get her to work.

Here's what i've got going on:

See the Pen [dynamic select](https://codepen.io/archaeopteryx/pen/gxYZPR/) by Archibald Hammer ([@archaeopteryx](https://codepen.io/archaeopteryx)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import _ from 'lodash'

const ITEMS = [
      { name: 'centos', text: 'centos', value: 'centosValue' },
      { name: 'ubuntu', text: 'ubuntu', value: 'ubuntuValue' },
]

const SelectComponent = (props) => (
  <select name={props.name}>
    {_.map(props.items, (item, i) => <Option
      key={i}
      name={item.name}
      value={item.value}
      text={item.text}
      handleSelect={props.handleSelect}
      />
    )}
  </select>
)

const Option = (props) => (
  <option 
    value={props.value} 
    onChange={props.handleSelect}>{props.text}</option>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      selected: ''
    }
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
  }
  handleSelect(e) {
    this.setState({selected: e.target.value})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectComponent 
          name="testSelect" 
          items={ITEMS} 
          handleSelect={this.handleSelect}
        />
        <div>
          <p>Selected: {this.state.selected}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

This code does render the dropdown selector as expected but it isn't triggering the setState on the selected item. Any thoughts?

Also, does anyone have any pro-tips for troubleshooting this kind of problem? Any super slick dev-tools you know of or methods for finding out which props are being passed, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the options in a select element won't trigger any event, the change is happening in the select element not the option. All you have to do is pass the `handleSelect` method to the `<select>` component:

```
const SelectComponent = (props) => (
  <select name={props.name}
    onChange={props.handleSelect}
  >
    {_.map(props.items, (item, i) => <Option
      key={i}
      name={item.name}
      value={item.value}
      text={item.text}
      handleSelect={props.handleSelect}
      />
    )}
  </select>
);

const Option = (props) => (
  <option 
    value={props.value} 
  >{props.text}</option>
)
```

Sorry I forgot to add the live sample link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/31AyQ2woR

In terms of a tip for debugging, in this particular case just know that the event is triggered by the select component and not the option element ;). But the one I use all the time is React developer tools:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/react-devtools/

Comment: Thanks a million! There is a slight bug when selecting the first element first though. I guess i'll have that just be the default selected item. If you click the first item it doesn't call setState for some reason. Thanks again! PS. I do use the React-dev-tools as well. It is pretty helpful.

Comment: yep, create an extra element in the array with an empty value, I've updated the sample, take a look.